# how to connect two different ssh connections to same ssh server

Tags: android, ssh, jsch, openssh

I am developing a system that connects two remote devices. I have used ssh for the whole communication. Scenario is such :

- Both devices connect to same ssh server having public ip
- Both devices are inside NAT
- Connection is initiated by both devices

Problem is that both connections are treated as different sessions and I want to make communication b/w the two devices possible.

I am using JSch

Another problem is that I want to use JSch in android and have no idea how to integrate and use JSch example files(say shell.java) in android

The two devices have already established connections to the server,this implies that the settings has to be at sshd (ssh server) that is maintaining this two authenticated sessions. Does SSH server allows this? If yes then how it could be done? Tell me if their is any another way to perform this i.e connecting two remote devices in different networks to communicate by connecting through one public IP.

I am using OpenSSH server just for relaying purpose but dont know how to relay input from one session to another session back and forth i.e I dont know how to configure SSH server

Answer (score 0):

You would have to build a "server" software on the server that would facilitate the communication between the devices.

You can still use the SSH and run the "server" software (or communicate with it) via the SSH/JSch session.

[image: Relaying]

You will run the software using JSch using the ["exec" channel](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/Exec.java.html). The software will communicate with other instances of itself using mechanism available on that platform, for example using [named pipes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named_pipe).

If you want a really trivial solution, you can just use `cat - > file` on one side and `tail -f file` on the other side. Try that in two SSH terminals to get the idea.

[image: Relaying]

---

You can hardly communicate between the devices directly otherwise.

Comment: I am using SSH server just for relaying purpose but dont know how to relay input from one session to another session back and forth i.e I dont know how to configure SSH server

Comment: I doubt your SSH server can be configured to "relay input from one session to another". Though you haven't told us what is your SSH server.

Comment: Again, in general, you have to write a server software for the relaying purposes.

Comment: session management is any applications internal process. SSH is a secure communication application that would not allow any third party application to access it's encrypted sessions and manipulate them unless it provide this feature explicitly.

Comment: You do not understand me. You can run the "server software" within the session.

Comment: I've added an illustration to my answer.

Comment: how this can be done. Kindly explain. I dont have an idea

Comment: You write a software (supposedly *nix, depending on what platform the server uses). You will run the software using JSch using the ["exec" channel](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/Exec.java.html). The software will communicate with other instances of itself using mechanism available on that platform, for example using [named pipes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named_pipe)

Comment: If you want a really trivial solution, you can just use `cat - > file` on one side and `tail -f file` on the other side. Try that in two SSH terminals to get the idea.